Alpine Expression Error: AlpineJS from Livewire Modal
I am using livewire modal package and using script to initiate alpine
<div class="p-2" x-data="data{{$listing->id}}" x-init="init()">
    <script>
        const data{{$listing->id}} = () => {
            return {
                marketplaces: @json($marketplaces),
                marketplaceExists: @json($marketplaceExists),
                total: 0,
                selected: @entangle('selected'),
                syncBudget: function() {
                    const data = this.marketplaces;
                    // Calculating budget
                    let total = 0;
                    this.selected.forEach(function(key) {
                        const obj = data[key]
                        total += parseInt(obj.price);
                    });
                    this.total = total;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    {{-- <x-primary-button x-on:click="console.log('test')">Test</x-primary-button> --}}
    <!-- Content -->
</div>

The main problem that i received this one

Alpine Expression Error: data1000001 is not defined

It seems that the script is no loaded while Alpine trying to load data.
The weird thing, if I directly put it into parent without loading it as modal. It is working.
Modal package
https://github.com/wire-elements/modal

Which "modal package" are you using? You should publish the complete Livewire component (class and view) and all the relevant code. Also a sample of the data should be useful. I see also a call to an inexistent init().

I have updated it, anyway I have found out the solution. Such a stupid mistake I dont really get AlpineJs basic. I got solution from your last comment on other thread. Thank you

This is the working one
<div class="p-2" x-data="() => {
        return {
            marketplaces: {{$marketplaces}},
            marketplaceExists: {{$marketplaceExists}},
            total: 0,
            selected: @entangle('selected'),
            syncBudget: function() {
                const data = this.marketplaces;
                // Calculating budget
                let total = 0;
                this.selected.forEach(function(key) {
                    const obj = data[key]
                    total += parseInt(obj.price);
                });
                this.total = total;
            }
        }
}">
    < !--Content -->
</div >

Just put the script inside x-data and it works. Seems the alpinejs read first before script loaded so I put it into the tag
